# How can I only install some modules from opencv after make install?

Tags: opencv

I am installing opencv 3.1.0 with extra modules and I need to install sfm module. I installed all the prerequisites as stated in the installation guide in sfm package, and ran this command from opencv_source_directory/release:

```
cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/git/opencv_contrib/modules ..
```

I can successfully create make file and install.

But I cannot find sfm.hpp under installation_path/include/opencv2/

Is there anything I missed? Thanks!

---

I found these in CMake command line output:

```
-- Found required Ceres dependency: Eigen version 3.2.8 in /usr/local/include/eigen3
-- Found required Ceres dependency: Glog in /usr/include
-- Found Ceres version: 1.12.0 installed in: /usr/local
-- Module opencv_sfm disabled because the following dependencies are not found: Glog/Gflags
```

But I did installed Glog/Gflags:

```
~$ sudo apt-get install libeigen3-dev libgflags-dev libgoogle-glog-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libgflags-dev is already the newest version.
libgoogle-glog-dev is already the newest version.
libeigen3-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Could anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved. Just remember to clear all the cmake cache files (remove the whole build folder) before running cmake again.