# Module opencv_sfm disabled because the following dependencies are not found: Glog/Gflags - both are detected

Tags: opencv, cmake, glog, opencv-contrib, gflags

I am not able to compile the sfm module for opencv using cmake.

The following log shows that cmake finds both glog and gflags, but compilation fails.

```
Glog:   YES
freetype2:   NO
harfbuzz:    NO
Julia not found. Not compiling Julia Bindings. 
Module opencv_ovis disabled because OGRE3D was not found
No preference for use of exported gflags CMake configuration set, and no hints for include/library directories provided. Defaulting to preferring an installed/exported gflags CMake configuration if available.
Found installed version of gflags: D:/ceres/gflags/out/build/x64-Debug
Detected gflags version: 2.2.2
WARNING: Target "cmTC_9b54b" requests linking to directory "D:/ceres/glog/out/build/x64-Debug".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
WARNING: Target "cmTC_9b54b" requests linking to directory "D:/ceres/glog/out/build/x64-Debug".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
WARNING: Target "cmTC_9b54b" requests linking to directory "D:/ceres/glog/out/build/x64-Debug".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
WARNING: Target "cmTC_9b54b" requests linking to directory "D:/ceres/glog/out/build/x64-Debug".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
Checking SFM deps... FALSE
Module opencv_sfm disabled because the following dependencies are not found: Glog/Gflags

Tesseract:   NO
Allocator metrics storage type: 'long long'
Registering hook 'INIT_MODULE_SOURCES_opencv_dnn': D:/opencv-4.5.0/modules/dnn/cmake/hooks/INIT_MODULE_SOURCES_opencv_dnn.cmake
opencv_dnn: filter out cuda4dnn source code
CMake Warning at D:/opencv-4.5.0/cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:679 (message):
  Unexpected include: D:/opencv-4.5.0/build/downloads/xfeatures2d
  (module=opencv_xfeatures2d)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  D:/opencv-4.5.0/cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:710 (ocv_target_include_modules)
  D:/opencv_contrib/modules/xfeatures2d/CMakeLists.txt:17 (ocv_module_include_directories)
```

Here is the code snippet from *"opencv_contrib\modules\sfm\CmakeLists.txt"* that causes the previous output:

```
if((gflags_FOUND OR GFLAGS_FOUND OR GFLAGS_INCLUDE_DIRS) AND (glog_FOUND OR GLOG_FOUND OR GLOG_INCLUDE_DIRS))
  set(_fname "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/test_sfm_deps.cpp")
  file(WRITE "${_fname}" "#include <glog/logging.h>\n#include <gflags/gflags.h>\n int main() { (void)(0); return 0; }\n")

  // This is reason of the fail
  try_compile(SFM_DEPS_OK "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}" "${_fname}"
      CMAKE_FLAGS "-DINCLUDE_DIRECTORIES:STRING=${GLOG_INCLUDE_DIRS};${GFLAGS_INCLUDE_DIRS}"
      LINK_LIBRARIES ${GLOG_LIBRARIES} ${GFLAGS_LIBRARIES}
      OUTPUT_VARIABLE OUTPUT
  )
  file(REMOVE "${_fname}")
  message(STATUS "Checking SFM deps... ${SFM_DEPS_OK}")
else()
  set(SFM_DEPS_OK FALSE)
endif()

if(NOT HAVE_EIGEN OR NOT SFM_DEPS_OK)
  set(DISABLE_MSG "Module opencv_sfm disabled because the following dependencies are not found:")
  if(NOT HAVE_EIGEN)
    set(DISABLE_MSG "${DISABLE_MSG} Eigen")
  endif()
  if(NOT SFM_DEPS_OK)
    set(DISABLE_MSG "${DISABLE_MSG} Glog/Gflags")
  endif()
  message(STATUS ${DISABLE_MSG})
  ocv_module_disable(sfm)
endif()
```

I think there is a problem in gflags and glog paths in cmake. I tried more variants. [Here is the current settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyqEM.png) Most of them are set based on [Ceres Solver documentation](http://ceres-solver.org/installation.html).

Configuration:

- OpenCV 4.5.0
- OpenCV-contrib 4.5.0
- glog 0.4.0
- gflags 2.2.2
- Ceres Solver 2.0.0
- eigen 3.3.9
- CMake 3.9.12
- Windows 10

Similar questions:

- [Module opencv_sfm disabled because the following dependencies are not found: Glog/Gflags #8536](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/8536) - Resolved for Ubuntu only.
- [How can I only install some modules from opencv after make install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35690411/how-can-i-only-install-some-modules-from-opencv-after-make-install) - Deleting the build folder did not help.
- [building opencv with sfm module issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62374063/building-opencv-with-sfm-module-issues) - Here he suggests downloading older versions of all parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the glog parameters in cmake set incorrectly.

Here is the correct setting:

- **glog_DIR**: Where is the build. There should be *glog-config.cmake*. Path: *glog/out/build/x64-Debug*
- **GLOG_LIBRARIES**: Where it is installed. Path to *glogd.lib*. Path: *glog/out/install/x64-Debug/lib/glogd.lib*
- **GLOG_INCLUDE_DIR**: Where it is installed. There should be folder named *glog*. Path: *glog/out/install/x64-Debug/include*